# Que signifie "vazerie" ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot

Dans *Féerie pour une autre fois* II :

> Qu'il crève pas le gaz !
>
> – C'est pas le gaz Ottave ?
>
> Si il crevait le gaz ?
>
> – Y a plus de gaz Ferdiiin' ! y a plus d'eau ! y a plus rien ! **vazerie** !

Je n'ai pas trouvé le mot *vazerie* dans le dictionnaire. Savez-vous ce qu'il signifie ?

Comment: Du pur Céline, à l'oreille : *va**z**erie* → *va**s**erie* (vasière :  https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vasi%C3%A8re)  et donc une *vazerie* semble être une situation *vaseuse* (https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vaseux B 2 familier). Qui sait faire tourner les tables pour faire valider cette hypothèse par Louis-Ferdinand ?

Comment: @Personne Merci beaucoup !

Comment: … écrit avec un ***s***, on aurait pu penser qu'il s'agissait d'un récipient.

Comment: Il y aussi vaser: https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vaser

Comment: @Personne Je penche plutôt pour une forme de  zézaiement que pour de la vase/vaseux. Vacherie me semble mieux coller avec le contexte. La vase en argot c'est aussi la chance mais dans le contexte ça ne colle pas.

Comment: Pas de souvenir de *‘vase’ = chance* du côté de La Rochelle, quel argot ou quelle région ? Avec la prononciation de l'occupant des films « C'est une grosseux vaZeuurie », les tables ont tourné :-) — À moins qu'il ne s'agisse du “vase de nuit” https://www.russki-mat.net/page.php?l=FrFr&a=Vase  que l'on retrouve dans l'urgence sans avoir à rallumer la chandelle !

Comment: @Personne Dictionnaire du français non conventionnel : avoir du vase, avoir de la chance. Mais comme je disais je ne pense pas que ça colle avec le contexte, sauf si ovide qui connait bien l’œuvre pense que, oui. Tiens vase chance est aussi au TLF, je viens de le voir.

Comment: Vu le TLF, mais je n'arrive pas à me faire une idée de ce "vase" : un récipient, un organe, une utilisation particulière du mot ?

Comment: @None Je viens de relire ce passage dans "Féerie II" et il me semble que l'hypothèse d'une forme de zézaiement de "vacherie" colle bien !

Comment: @Personne Le dictionnaire du français non conventionnel ne donne pas l'origine avec certitude, rejette plutôt l'organe (anus) et penche pour le récipient (vase →  bol).

Comment: @None … cohérent, belle recherche ! :-)

Comment: @Personne pas moi qui ai fait la recherche, c'est J. Cellard et A. Rey !

Answer (score 4):

*Vazerie* pourrait bien être l'expression d'une forme de zézaiement pour *vacherie*. Dans le zézaiement le son /ʃ/ (ch) est remplacé par le son /s/ et le son /ʒ/ (j) est remplacé par le son /z/. Céline aurait fait une forme de néologisme en remplaçant le son /ʃ/ par le son /z/.
Bref, ce qui leur arrive est une véritable [vacherie](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/vacherie).

Answer (score 1):

Créée de toute pièce par Ferdinand Celine; signifie à la fois "bordel" et "vacherie".

Comment: Ceci ne répond pas à la question "Que signifie "vazerie" ?"

Comment: Signifie à la fois bordel et vacherie

Comment: Peux-tu expliquer le rapport avec bordel ?

Comment: Pouvez-vous donner une source pour cette information, s'il vous plaît ?